# Discard all parameters of method (Remove unused parameter 'sender' and 'args')

Tags: c#, uwp, c#-7.0

#### The situation

When assigning a `Click` event to a button, I get a premade eventhandler which specifies an `object sender` and `RoutedEventArgs args`.

Now for my implementation of this eventhandler I don't use `sender` and `args`, and therefore I get a message saying that I should remove the parameters.

I am aware of the discard (`_`) operator in C#, however using this allows me to only discard one of the parameters (if I use `_` again for `args` I get an error saying that I already have a parameter called `_`).

I have searched over the internet but there are only examples of discarding `out` variables, using discard in lambda expressions, etc. but nothing about this.

For example I want to convert something like this:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    DoSomethingThatDoesNotUseSenderAndArgs();
}
```

to this:

```cs
private void Button_CLick(object _, RoutedEventArgs _)
{
    DoSomethingThatDoesNotUseSenderAndArgs();
}
```

#### My question

Should I just ignore this message? Or suppress it since there does not seem to be a way of solving it without using the parameters in the implementation? Or is there actually a way of discarding both parameters and thus remove this annoying message?

Comment: can you share a small code-sample?

Comment: Discards are placeholder variables that are intentionally unused in application code! In this case, you try to use discards for parameters, not variables. It is impossible in such way

Comment: @RomanMarusyk so its just not allowed to do this? Should I then just suppress the message?

Comment: I would suppress it

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards `If it were an actual variable, you could not discard more than one value, as the previous example did.` You can probably do it as a lambda expression though - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#input-parameters-of-a-lambda-expression . If it was me though, I'd leave it as is - it is an event handler, and people understand how they work.

Comment: @mjwills Too bad, think I'll have to just suppress the message then

Comment: What's the error code? CS????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my question by accident:

Whereas

```cs
private void Button_CLick(object _, RoutedEventArgs _) { }
```

will give an error on the second underscore,

```cs
private void Button_CLick(object _, RoutedEventArgs __) { }
```

will not.

Comment: I just want to clarify for others that this is *NOT* discarding the parameters, but rather naming both of them to `_` and `__` respectively.